# Playing new audio source changed by jquery

Tags: jquery, audio, html5-audio, audio-player

everyone

I wrote simple music player, but I have one problem. I used ajax to get new source from file php and that works OK, but I have no idea how play new song. Simple audio.play() doesn't work. I try to repair  This is my code:

```
    function timer(){
    timeleft = $("span#timeleft");
    slider = $("div#slider");
    $(audio).bind('timeupdate', function(){
        var rem = parseInt(audio.duration - audio.currentTime, 10),
        pos = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 315,
        mins = Math.floor(rem/60, 10),
        secs = rem - mins*60;

        timeleft.text('- ' + mins + ':' + (secs > 9 ? secs : '0' + secs));
        slider.css({width: pos + 'px'});
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    audio = $("audio#audio-player-header").get(0);

    $("div#controls").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("pause");
        if(audio.paused){
            audio.play();
            timer();
        }else{
            audio.pause();
        }
    });

    audio.addEventListener("ended", function(){
            $.post("php/player.php", function(result){
                audio.src = result;
            });
            audio.play(); // here is the problem
            timer();
    });
});
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="player">
                    <div id="controls" class="play"></div>
                    <div id="music-title">
                        <div id="slider">
                            <div id="wrap-music-title">
                                <p id="music-title">Jamie T - Chaka Demus</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span id="timeleft"></span>
                    <div id="player-header">
                    <audio id="audio-player-header" src="music/rock/Jamie T - Chaka Demus.mp3">
                    </audio>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I found on stackoverflow and web some solutions, but nothing works here. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created a race condition in which you're calling `audio.play()` before your ajax call returns. You could  (A)listen for the audio `canplay` event then trigger play or (B)just set the `autoplay` attribute of your audio tag.

Option A:

```
audio.addEventListener("ended", function(){
    $.post("php/player.php", function(result){
        audio.src = result;
    });
});

audio.addEventListener("canplay", function(){
    audio.play();
});
```

Option B:

```
<audio autoplay id="audio-player-header" src="music/rock/Jamie T - Chaka Demus.mp3">
```

Comment: Brian, thanks for quickly answer. I've thought about autoplay earlier, even I tried to put it in code when the first song is ended but it also doesn't work. I've already checked your suggestion but still player is stopping after the first song, here is my website: http://wovich.net46.net/musicon/ Maybe it makes only me angry :D

Comment: There's something wrong with the second MP3 you are trying to load (`http://wovich.net46.net/musicon/music/rap/Lady Leshur Lego.mp3`). Try hitting that URL in a browser and you'll see that file won't play. I took the code from your page and put it on my server it works fine if you update the src with a valid audio file.

Comment: I can't believe that one valid source took me two weeks considering what's wrong in code. Thanks again for help, solution was so close.